# Reduce global state in web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, global-variables, session-variables

There are numerous posts available on alternatives to global state, but I have lingering questions regarding implementation in a web environment.

In ASP.NET, values stored in the session are practically global variables, but it seems you can't reasonably store, e.g., authenticated username, permissions, etc. across pages and events without resorting to the `Session[]` collection. (I would typically use dependency injection, but you wouldn't want to pass these values in the viewstate/url to the client.)

So I take that global state is a necessary evil in web development (due to the stateless nature of HTTP) and the answer is to just use it responsibly. What is a good facade pattern for implementation? A static class such as the one below that just `get`s and `set`s values in the session doesn't do much to mask the global state.

```
public class SessionWrapper
{
    public static string UserName
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]); }
        set { Session["UserName"] = value; }
    }
    public static bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsAuthenticated"]); }
        set { Session["IsAuthenticated"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question. Are you saying that you need to avoid storing state on the server (e.g. in a database or memory cache)?

Comment: I do not understand your question ether. (can you please give some post about the alternative to global state ?)

Comment: No, I'm asking how all the typical pitfalls of global variables can be avoided in large web applications which generally *must* use the session (e.g., for authentication values, settings, etc.). See [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: To clarify, I'm asking how techniques such as dependency injection can be used to eliminate global variables in web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global *variables* are problematic but global *values* are fine. So if you want to mitigate the “problems” of global state simply make those objects immutable (I don't see how DI is all that relevant).

The `User` property of the `HttpContext` object is useful for storing such state since it needs to be available to every part of your application but can only be assigned early in the pipeline.

So, just come up with your own implementation of `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal` that has the extra properties you want and assign it to `HttpContext.Current.User` during, say, the `AuthenticateRequest` event.

Comment: As far as I can tell, DI *isn't* relevant to circumventing issues with global state in web applications, but it's the most common solution I've seen (online) to the problem of global state in general, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @JustinSatyr No worries. When I said that I didn't see how DI was relevant I was being genuine... there may have been something more about the problem that you knew that I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

What I like about this is that it defines a *fixed* set of state variables shared globally. With uncontrolled use of `Session` there is all sorts of junk that gets there with different names for same entity and what not.

Of course, you still need to somehow ensure that `Session` is not used directly.

Answer (score 0):

As you use them here are not global variables - but a nice "interface" to access your session variables.

They may have problem if the session was handle with out any locking mechanism, but asp.net session is locking the full access to session across all pages, so you do now have any issue with that.